# pps device is automatically removed after calling ldattach

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My work system (Ubuntu 16.04 x64) has GNSS receiver attached to a serial port /dev/ttyS6 and provide PPS signal through the port. Early ldattach 18 /dev/ttyS6 creates /dev/pps0 (as expected). But since this monday it doesn't create the pps device (/dev/pps0).

dmesg | grep -i pps shows that the device was created and then was removed in less than second.

```
[    1.018267] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    1.018268] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[ 1007.490177] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[ 1007.490404] pps pps0: new PPS source serial6
[ 1007.490412] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyS6" added
[ 1007.729611] pps pps0: removed
```

I've spend the whole day but didn't find a solution.
Let me know if any additional info is required.
Any leads would be appreciated.

P.S. There are no any udev's rules or systemd services for auto rising the pps device. And there is no other running instances of the ldattach.

UP: The part of dmesg log without grep

```
[   44.196119] aufs au_opts_verify:1623:dockerd[2636]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 1007.490177] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[ 1007.490404] pps pps0: new PPS source serial6
[ 1007.490412] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyS6" added
[ 1007.729611] pps pps0: removed
[ 1540.200506] pps pps0: new PPS source serial6
```

UP: ldattach -d output

```
[grin@grinDesktop ~]$ sudo ldattach -d 18 /dev/ttyS6
ldattach: opened /dev/ttyS6
ldattach: set to raw 0 ---: cflag=0x14b2
ldattach: line discipline set to 18
```

SOLUTION: the cause was in unreliable connection (to serial port on PCI-E card). After reconnection the cable the problem has gone. Thank you all for your help. =)

Comment: First step is to read `dmesg` directly without `grep`, and see if anything interesting happens between 1007.490412 and 1007.729611. `grep` is fine to quickly see if a particular pattern is in the log file, but restricting your visible output to `grep` while diagnosing bugs is a cardinal sin (pet peeve of mine, sorry for the rant).

Comment: @dirkt, thanks for your comment. I've checked dmesg - there are no any other lines between those three lines (new, added, removed).

Comment: Can you run `ldattach -d` manually and share the output?

Comment: Hello @Attie, thanks for your commit. I've added the output to the post. It seems like alright, but dmesg contains the same three new lines (new, added, removed) and there is no /dev/ppsX device.